# EF Core Returns one Record where Many are Expected when Using Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a database that stores data regarding Facilities, Doctors, and revenue for both of the previous items - FacilityRevenue and DoctorRevenue.  There are also FaciltyMaster and DoctorMaster tables that have a one to many relationship with the FacilityRevenue and DoctorRevenue tables.  That is, one doctor or facility master record is related to many DoctorId or FacilityId records in the FacilityRevenue and DoctorRevenue tables.  I've attempted to place foreign key relationships so that DoctorId on DoctorRevenue relates to DoctorId on DoctorMaster and FacilityId on FacilityRevenue relates to FacilityId on FaclityMaster.  However, I'm not confident that Entity Framework is reading this as such.

The model for each is as follows:

```
public partial class FacilityMaster
{
    public FacilityMaster()
    {
        DoctorRevenue = new HashSet<DoctorRevenue>();
        FacilityRevenue = new HashSet<FacilityRevenue>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DoctorRevenue> DoctorRevenue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FacilityRevenue> FacilityRevenue { get; set; }
}

public partial class DoctorMaster
{
    public DoctorMaster()
    {
        DoctorRevenue = new HashSet<DoctorRevenue>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
    public string DoctorSpecialty { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DoctorRevenue> DoctorRevenue { get; set; }
}



 public partial class DoctorRevenue
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public decimal? DoctorInvoices { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalRevenue { get; set; }

    public virtual DoctorMaster Doctor { get; set; }
    public virtual FacilityMaster Facility { get; set; }
}

public partial class FacilityRevenue
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalInvoices { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalRevenue { get; set; }

    public virtual FacilityMaster Facility { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured, in part, my FacilityRevenueRepository as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<FacilityRevenue> GetFacRevenues(Int32 pageSize, Int32 pageNumber, String name)
    {
        var query = _context
            .Set<FacilityRevenue>()
            .AsQueryable()
            .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            query = query.Where(item => item.FacilityName.Contains(name));
        }
        return query;
    }
```

The relevant portion of my FacilityRevenueController is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("GetFacilityRevenues")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFacilityRevenues(Int32? pageSize = 10, Int32? pageNumber = 1, String FacilityName = null)
    {
        var response = new ListModelResponse<FacRevViewModel>() as IListModelResponse<FacRevViewModel>;

        try
        {
            response.PageSize = (Int32)pageSize;
            response.PageNumber = (Int32)pageNumber;

            response.Model = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return FacilityRevenueRepository
                .GetFacRevenues(response.PageNumber, response.PageSize, FacilityName)
                .Select(item => item.ToViewModel())
                .ToList();
            });
            response.Message = String.Format("Total Records {0}", response.Model.Count());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.DidError = true;
            response.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return response.ToHttpResponse();
    }
```

The DbContext is as follows:

```
    public partial class ERPWAGDbContext : DbContext
    {
    public ERPWAGDbContext(DbContextOptions<ERPWAGDbContext> options)
        :base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<DoctorMaster> Doctors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FacilityMaster> Facilities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DoctorRevenue> DoctorRevenue { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FacilityRevenue> FacilityRevenue { get; set; }

    }
```

When I run this using `dotnet run`, Postman returns just one record for GetFacilityRevenues, where several hundred are expected.

How do I ensure that all records for a given facility are returned, and likewise for doctors, when my GetFacilities and GetDoctors API methods are called?

Comment: Not sure if that's the cause of the concrete issue, but `Where` should be before `Skip` / `Take`.

Comment: Can you show your DbContext code ?

Comment: I'm agree with Ivan, have you tried to apply where before paging ?

Comment: @H.Herzl I've just included DbContext.

Comment: @IvanStoev I moved the Where before Skip and Take to no avail.  Also, the FacilityMaster portion of the API has the same structure and returns all records.

Comment: Just a question, but have you checked your value of page size. If it is 1 then that's all you will get.

Comment: Also, you have some unnecessary things in your query. There is no reason to use the .Set<> because all that does is creates a DbSet which you already have according to your DbContext  and there is no need for the AsQueryable because a DbSet inherits from IQueryable<TEntity>. So your query should look more like _context.FacilityRevenue.Where(item => item.FacilityName.Contains(name)).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);